# Merge the "macintosh" tag into "apple" or "os-x"?

Tags: support, tags, tag-naming

We have [macintosh](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/macintosh), but Apple hasn't used this term for their computers since 1998 (they just use "Mac"). The tag wiki suggests that this is for questions about the hardware rather than software, but usage doesn't really reflect that — and questions about the computer hardware would generally be off-topic anyway.

I suggest merging this tag into either [apple](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) or [os-x](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/os-x).

Comment: Or maybe rename it to Mac?

Comment: I can't remember, if you merge two tags, for example merge tag "Red" into "Green"; if a user types "Red" in the future does it resolve automatically to "Green"?

Comment: @dpollitt Yeah — it makes an automatic synonym

Comment: @romeo Yeah, maybe, but can you think of a case where Apple or OS X wouldn't do?

Comment: @mattdm, This was just one idea. And Apple use this word (MacBook, iMac, Mac mini). My observations also show me many people use the word Mac when mention Apple computer (previous Macintosh)

Answer (score 1):

Merge Macintosh into Apple.

Leave OS-X alone.

People will use Apple when referring to the hardware components of the personal computer manufacturer, and OS-X when they are referring to the software that Apple produces for the desktop environment.

Comment: Works for me, but I think the Apple tag might also be applied to software other than OS X which Apple also makes. (Like Aperture or iPhoto.)

Comment: I'm inclined to think that specific software will generally land on their own tag (e.g. Aperture).

Comment: JoanneC: Unless it's spotlight:) Exhibit A: https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/67641/4892

Comment: Spotlight is part of the OS, should be more correctly tagged for OS X. :)

Comment: Yeah that is a good point. A lot of the photography related software on OS-X actually is included with the OS like iPhoto or whatever it is called these days. So one tag might not make sense either.

Comment: Yes and no... iPhoto is gone, but the replacement "Photos" is actually an add-on, you can remove it and many do. It's basically part of a free suite of productivity apps that Apple makes available. In any event, the reason the collection of us is here is to curate some of that anyways. :)